# Do i really need a Dedicated IP address to send push notifications to APNS

Tags: php, ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications

The question has already been asked on this forum but my concern in different. I have shared server space on Crazy domains and Blue Host. I have tried sending push notification with both of them. When i try it on Crazy Domain I get the following error:

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196 (Connection timed out) in /home4/karmamob/public_html/pushNotification/api.php on line 20
Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out

When i run the same on Crazy Domain , I get the following error.

Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196 (Connection timed out) in /home4/karmamob/public_html/pushNotification/api.php on line 20
Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out

There should be no issues with the certificate because it runs fine on my local mac PC.

What i want to ask is, Can I solve this problem if I buy a Dedicated IP from BLUE HOST?

Comment: Why not use a 3rd party push notification service like Parse: https://www.parse.com/products/push (free for <= 1,000,000 messages per month)

Comment: really is that around 1000000? What are the charges if we exceed? Can you tell me?

Comment: https://www.parse.com/products/push#pricing - basic plan = $0.07 per 1,000 over 1M. Pro is ~$200 for 5 Million and $0.05 per 1,000 over (plus you get more features).

Comment: I need to pay $3 every month for a dedicated IP... Payment is not a problem. Will my issue get solved with a dedicated IP?

Answer (score 1):

No you don't. Shared hosting plans tend to have controlled environments that you, as a shared user, can't really change, such as open or blocked ports. Is there any way you can check if connections through port 2196 are being successfully established (not necessarily to Apple)? Some low-cost, shared plans are known for blocking some juice in favour of stability and security. Also check if your push certs are properly uploaded. Cheers.

Comment: actually had a chat with the Blue host support people. I asked them to open up the port for me. They told me to purchase a dedicated IP to do that.....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as NewObjective clarified, 2195 & 2196 ports have to be open. To open these ports you might ask Bluehost technical support team (ticket/chat), but you have to have dedicated IP address before that.

But there is another issue. If you try to send push notification message right after dedicated IP address is set and both ports are open you might receive the same "Connection timed out" error. You can test that problem by logging in to your server via SSH and running "telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195" command. If you receive "Connection timed out" error - you can try to contact Bluehost support team, but they can't solve this problem.

If you try to telnet any other server with 2195 opened port you will also receive that error. I had about 10 chats with Bluehost support team, opened 10 or so tickets, but they really couldn't help me. But two weeks later everything began to work. I think it was because turning dedicated IP on takes some time, but I'm not sure. Anyway, it very interesting that Bluehost support team always answers that the problem is on the Apple side, even if you tell them that any other server with 2195 opened port isn't available too)
[image]